# C++ - UDP server with multiple clients

Tags: c++, windows, server, udp, winsock

I'm learning the sockets. I am writing a simple UDP server, through which small messages are sent. All active clients send "keepalive" messages every three minutes so that the server can see which clients are online.

These messages are received in the stream

Stream function:

```
void keepAlive(SOCKET udp)
{
int len=0;
while(true)
{
 int len=recvfrom(udp,requestBuffer,maxMessage,0,(sockaddr*)&cliAddr,&cliAddrSize)
// Actions with the received message
}
}
```

But how to implement, for example, the transmission of messages to all clients or a specific one, if the socket is already "busy". Need to create a new socket to send messages? (On the server and on the client)?  And if the clients are behind NAT?

The same question is also on the client's side (because keepalive is taken out to the thread, but when solving this problem, the other is being solved too)

Answer (score 0):

After the server receive the keepalive message,you already got the client address in cliAddr.
Then you can use the sendto function to send something to the client.
if you want use other sockets， you can make it.
And if the clients are behind NAT? 
It doesn't matter. If the server got a WAN address, the router will convert the ip address and port in the LAN to the WAN address and port.the client address you got in the server is a WAN address and port. WAN(address and port)--map--LAN(address and port).

In the client I suggest you make a thread to recv message and process them(include keepalive message or other type).

Comment: I do not want to send an answer right away. I want to do this at any time, but my socket will be busy waiting for keep-alive.

Comment: In the server, if you do not want to block the recvfrom, you can create another thread to process the event or the message you recv. in  the other threads you can decide to send in any time.